# Does the .equ Arm assembly directive support inversion?

Tags: stm32, assembler

The .equ directive is used to make constants:

```
.equ PERIPH_BASE, 0x40000000
```

This directive supports some operands like add, substruct or even shift:

```
.equ APB2PERIPH_BASE, (PERIPH_BASE + 0x00010000)
.equ GPIO_PIN_15,     (0x00000001 << 15)
```

I need to invert the value so I tried this:

```
.equ GPIO_PIN_15_INV,      (~GPIO_PIN_15)
```

In the disassembly window in the SMT32Cube IDE I see that my instruction

```
ORNS R0, R5, GPIO_PIN_15_INV
```

Changes to

```
08000166: orrs.w r0, r5, #32768  ; 0x8000
```

In other words, the value of GPIO_PIN_15 doesn't invert.

Is it possible to make an inverted constant with .equ? If yes, how? Where can I read about this possibility?

Comment: your question is better suited for https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Comment: try arithmetic complement ... what do you get with `.equ ABC123, (0 - 5 - 1)`?

Comment: You're using the `ORNS` instruction, which ["performs an OR operation on the bits in Rn with the **complements** of the corresponding bits in the value of Operand2"](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/i/arm-and-thumb-instructions/orn--thumb-only-), and your Operand2 is already the bit-wise complement of 0x8000. So it's functionally equivalent to just OR with 0x8000. You fed the assembler a "double negative".

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple way how to replace negation by other operations. One of them (in my opinion the easiest one) is XOR with full one pattern:

```
.equ GPIO_PIN_15_INV,      (GPIO_PIN_15 ^ 0xFFFF)
```

Test it yourself: https://godbolt.org/z/nKK4c8Wsf

Side notice: with 0xFFFFFFFF it will not work because ARM assembly is unable to encode 32-bit constants in the instruction word (which is 16 or 32-bit wide, so there is no space for such large constants).